# Validar hora fin mayor a hora inicio en timepicker de Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap-3

Tengo dos `input` con la `class="timepicker"` de `Boostrap` para ingresar hora de inicio y hora de finalización.

```js
$("#horaFin").change(function(){
 $(".alert").remove();
 var horaInicio = $("#horaInicio").val();
 var horaFin = $("#horaFin").val();
 if (horaFin <= horaInicio) {
  $("#horaFin").parent().after('<div class="alert alert-warning">La hora de finalización debe ser mayor a la hora de inicio</div>');
  $("#horaFin").val("");
 } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" name="horaInicio" id="horaInicio" placeholder="Ingresar hora de inicio" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" name="horaFin" id="horaFin" placeholder="Ingresar hora de finalización" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
```

El usuario no puede ingresar horas inferiores a `#horaInicio` en `#horaFin`. Por ejemplo:

**Inicio: 21:00**

**Fin: 18:00**

Esta acción muestra una alerta y borra el contenido de `#horaFin` para que el usuario ingrese nuevamente la hora.

La única excepción permitida sería cuando `#horaInicio` sea menor o igual a **23:00** y `#horaFin` sea igual a **00:00**

Cómo puedo realizar esa validación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví creando esta validación previa:

```
if (horaFin == "00:00" && horaInicio > horaFin) {
```

```js
$("#horaFin").blur(function(){
 $(".alert").remove();
 var horaInicio = $("#horaInicio").val();
 var horaFin = $("#horaFin").val();
 if (horaFin == "00:00" && horaInicio > horaFin) {
  $("#horaFin").parent().after(
   '<div class="alert alert-success">Bien hecho! <br> Finalizaste la jornada para esta fecha.</div>'
  );
 } else if (horaFin <= horaInicio) {
  $("#horaFin").parent().after(
   '<div class="alert alert-warning">Intenta de nuevo! <br> La hora de finalización debe ser mayor a la hora de inicio</div>'
  );
  $("#horaFin").val("");
 } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" name="horaInicio" id="horaInicio" placeholder="Ingresar hora de inicio" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" name="horaFin" id="horaFin" placeholder="Ingresar hora de finalización" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
```